# public, private, signal, etc inditation using uncrustify?

Tags: c++, qt, code-formatting, uncrustify

Where in uncrustify's configuration can I find `public`, `private`, `protected`, and Qt's `slots` and `signals` indentation? For example to change this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
   ~MyClass();
private:
    void method();
};
```

... to this:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();
       ~MyClass();
    private:
        void method();
};
```

?

Comment: What are _slots_ and _signals_ regarding standard c++?

Comment: It isn't c++ reserved word, it is qt framework special keyword.

Comment: Then you should probably add the [tag:qt] tag (I know well BTW).

Comment: Ok, I've added tag

Comment: Another option: You don't need to worry about these special keywords if you use `Q_SIGNAL` and `Q_SLOT` instead :)

Comment: Yes, actually I know about these Q_SIGNAL and Q_SLOT macros. But I prefer to user `signal` and `slot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally find parameters that can do it:

```
indent_access_spec = 0 
indent_access_spec_body = true
```

Comment: This also requires ```indent_class = true```